# Azure DevOps: How can I run powershell on onPrem servers after deployment of all IIS Sites

Tags: azure-devops

How can I run a powershell script after all stages have completed deployment? I have currently selected a deployment group job but am not 100% sure if this is what I need. I have included the script as part of the solution that is being deployed so that it will be available on all machines. Based on what I can find in the UI there seem to be 2 tasks that could work.

The first option would be to execute the task "Powershell Script" but it is asking for a path in the drop directory. The problem with this is that the file that I am interested in is in a zip file and there does not seem to be a way to specify a file in the zip file.

The other task I see is "PowerShell on Target Machines" and then it asks for a list of target machines. I am not sure what needs to be entered here as I want to run the powershell script on the current machine in the deploy group. It seems like this task was intended to run powershell scripts from the deployment machine to another remote machine. As a result this option does not seem like it fits my use case.

From looking the answers that I have come across talk about how to do this as part of an Azure site using something called "Kudu" (not relevant) or don't answer my other questions related to these tasks or seem like they are out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A deployment group job will run on all of the servers specified in that deployment group. Based on what you have indicated, it sounds like that is what you are looking for.

Since you indicated that the file in question is a zip, you are actually going to need to use 2 separate tasks.

1. Extract Files - use this to extract the zip file so that you can execute the script
2. Powershell script - use this to execute the script. You can set the working directory for the script to execute in if necessary (under advanced options). Also remember that you don't have to use the file/folder selector 'helper' as it wont work in your case if the file is inside a zip. This is just used to populate the text box which you can manually do starting with the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) variable and adding the necessary path of the script.

Comment: I don't think I was very clear. I just meant the when I use the path selector I end up with a path like: drop\environment\projectFiles.zip. I understand that this gets deployed to the server and that the file I am interested in will be here. Based on your second point it seems that I should be able to do something like: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\MyPath\ToTheFile\myScript.ps1 and it will run this file on the local machine? Assuming that the path is exists on the local machine.

Comment: I managed to figure this out. Just for the sake of trying something I set up a copy file task. I set the target path like so: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/Deployment`. This will put the contents of this folder in the artifacts directory. Now you will be able to use the path selector in the powershell task to select the files that you need to run.